# Val_loss is nan at very first of training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

`val_loss` is NaN at very first of training.

The Structure

```
def trainingResNet(source_folder):

    # Preprocessing
    image_gen_train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=90, horizontal_flip=True)
    image_gen_train.fit(x1_train)

    # Load Model
    model = Network_frame.ResNet18([2, 2, 2, 2])
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
                  metrics=['sparse_categorical_accuracy'])
    training_dir = '#%s adam_sca_Undistort' % '5'
    checkpoint_save_path = os.path.join('checkpoint', training_dir, 'model.{epoch:02d}-{loss:.2f}.ckpt')

    # Callback setting
    log_dir = os.path.join('cnnlogs', training_dir)
    cp_callback = [
        tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=0),
        tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_save_path, save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, monitor='loss', mode='min'),
        tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.5, patience=5, min_delta=0.005, mode='auto', min_lr=0.0001)]

    # Training
    history = model.fit([x1_train, x2_train], y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=800,
                        validation_data=([x1_test, x2_test], y_test), validation_freq=1, callbacks=cp_callback)
```

Network frame

```
class ResNetBlock(Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, strides=1, residual_path=False):
        super(ResNetBlock, self).__init__()
        self.filters = filters
        self.strides = strides
        self.residual_path = residual_path

        self.c1 = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), strides=strides, padding='same', use_bias=False)
        self.b1 = BatchNormalization()
        self.a1 = Activation('relu')

        self.c2 = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False)
        self.b2 = BatchNormalization()

        if residual_path:
            self.down_c1 = Conv2D(filters, (1, 1), strides=strides, padding='same', use_bias=False)
            self.down_b1 = BatchNormalization()

        self.a2 = Activation('relu')

    def call(self, inputs):
        residual = inputs

        x = self.c1(inputs)
        x = self.b1(x)
        x = self.a1(x)

        x = self.c2(x)
        y = self.b2(x)

        if self.residual_path:
            residual = self.down_c1(inputs)
            residual = self.down_b1(residual)

        out = self.a2(y + residual)

        return out

class ResNet18(Model):
    def __init__(self, block_list, initial_filters=64):
        super(ResNet18, self).__init__()
        self.num_blocks = len(block_list)
        self.block_list = block_list
        self.out_filters = initial_filters
        self.c1_1 = Conv2D(self.out_filters, (7, 7), strides=1, padding='same', use_bias=False,
                           kernel_initializer='he_normal')
        self.b1_1 = BatchNormalization()
        self.a1_1 = Activation('relu')
        self.p1_1 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=1, padding='same')
        self.blocks = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

        for block_id in range(len(block_list)):
            for layer_id in range(block_list[block_id]):
                if block_id != 0 and layer_id == 0:
                    block = ResNetBlock(self.out_filters, strides=2, residual_path=True)
                else:
                    block = ResNetBlock(self.out_filters, residual_path=False)
                self.blocks.add(block)
            self.out_filters *= 2
        self.p2_1 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()
        self.f1_1 = Dense(512, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))
        self.d1_1 = Dropout(0.2)
        self.f2_1 = Dense(64, activation='relu', )

        self.f1_2 = Dense(16, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))
        self.d1_2 = Dropout(0.2)
        self.f2_2 = Dense(16, activation='relu', )

        self.f1 = Dense(64, activation='relu', )
        self.d1 = Dropout(0.2)
        self.f2 = Dense(32, activation='relu', )
        self.d2 = Dropout(0.2)
        self.f3 = Dense(40, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs):
        x1 = self.c1_1(inputs[0])
        x1 = self.b1_1(x1)
        x1 = self.a1_1(x1)
        x1 = self.p1_1(x1)
        x1 = self.blocks(x1)
        x1 = self.p2_1(x1)
        x1 = self.f1_1(x1)
        x1 = self.d1_1(x1)
        x1 = self.f2_1(x1)

        x2 = self.f1_2(inputs[1])
        x2 = self.d1_2(x2)
        x2 = self.f2_2(x2)

        x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x1, x2])
        x = self.f1(x)
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = self.f2(x)
        x = self.d2(x)
        y = self.f3(x)
        return y
```

The network can be fitted normally, but val_loss is NaN at the first epoch

```
2864/2875 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 13.3955 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0583
2875/2875 [==============================] - 73s 25ms/sample - loss: 13.3595 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0584 - val_loss: nan - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.0668
Epoch 2/800
```

The network can be fitted normally, but val_loss is NaN at the first epoch

The approaches that have been tried

- Use other version of TF (currently 2.1)
- Use LeakyReLU instead of ReLU
- Decrease lr
- Make sure the input does not have NaN
- Make sure the target is computable by the loss function (greater than 0)

I would like to ask if there is any way to fix it or
it is possible to reproduce the `val_loss` calculation to get the location of the NaN if the model checkpoint is saved

Many thanks

Comment: have you tried passing the validation dataset as training dataset to see if the problem repeat itself? or did you do all the tests with differents shuffle of the validation datasets?

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow hi. That`s a very good point. I just tried to use val dataset as training dataset and the loss becomes NaN. But I double checked the val dataset numpy itself is not include NaN in it. Thus, it seems the problem is come with calculation on val data

Comment: if you use it as training dataset and you put it at bach of 1 you can understand what is the particular sample that is giving you the problem ( if the training is fast you can also print the output on file). This is a really scuffed solution but it gets the job done, then you will have to investigate only a sample

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2850#issuecomment-719836693     at this link you find a way to print the loss every batch, now you need only to check when it gets NaN and you have your outliar

Comment: @BestDogeStackoverflow Hi again, I am now pretty sure that there is some unknown problem with one of the data in the test dataset.
But I am also sure that there is no broken data in the dataset itself, so maybe it is the particular format of the data that is causing the NaN problem. I am dividing the test set into smaller pieces to clean the data in batches. Many thanks!